# Hangfire Recursive Process Doesn't Start

Tags: asp.net, cron, hangfire

I have a function that I want it to execute recursively using a variable time interval
when I use the expressions provided by the Cron class the function executes just fine, how ever when I try to use a Cron expression that I wrote myself it doesn't do so

those lines get executed in the Application_Start event in my ASP.NET web forms application

```
 string strCronExpressionMinutes = "1/{0} * * * *";
 string recurrsionCronExp = String.Format(strCronExpressionMinutes, strShiftCheckingRate);
 WebApp.Start<Startup1>(strBaseURL);
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => driverManager.RegisterDriverAttendence(), recurrsionCronExp);
```

if I understood write this Cron expression is supposed to repeat the function every strShiftCheckingRate number of minutes however it doesn't
could anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code in ASP.NET MVC 5 Controller and it's work fine (Hangfire 1.5.3):

```
public string New(int minutes = 15)
    {          
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ClassName>(a => a.DoJob(), string.Format("*/{0} * * * *", minutes));
        return string.Format("ClassName->DoJob()"); 
    }
```

Have you configured Handfire correctly?

```
     var backgroundJobServerOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            Queues = new[] { "default" }
        };
        app.UseHangfireServer(backgroundJobServerOptions);
```

Can you configure breakpoint at this line: *RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => driverManager.RegisterDriverAttendence(), recurrsionCronExp);*?